# ARM IF-ELSE unexpected characters at end of line

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I'm trying to do a conditional assembly:

```
IF {TRUE}
    ; do stuff
ELSE
    ; other stuff
ENDIF
```

(I'd change TRUE to FALSE to switch the branches)

But Keil is giving me error:

```
error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
```

What's the problem? Replacing `{TRUE}` with `1` or anything else doesn't help.

Ideally I'd have something like

```
X    EQU 1

IF X
    ; do stuff
ELSE
    ; other stuff
ENDIF
```

but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved now. The problem was that it wants a tab BEFORE the directives.

Comment: armasm uses one of those old-fashioned "anything that starts in the first column is a label" syntaxes, [as the manual says](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731141352.htm).